# Notify Apache Camel when delete File

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

I want to write a DSL route where I want to notify Camel when deleting any file having the extension ".log" in the directory "src/main/resources".

```
from(????????)
.bean(MyProcess.class)
.end
```

Thank you for your help!
Reda

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484212/apache-camel-2-10-7-monitor-deletion-of-files-from-file-system

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct way to achieve this. But we can poll the directory periodically and get the list of files which can be stored in a list. In the next poll we can compare the two list and find the difference.

```
.from("file:path?noop=true&idempotent=false&delay=60s")
```